# i am making a chair and i find there black uniteractable lines

Tags: mesh

i am making a chair and i find there black uniteractable lines[image]

they are quite annoying, i want to know how to remove them/hide them so i can continue

(entire screen)
[image]

modifier tab[image]

(modifier tab)

Comment: You should add a picture of your modifiers settings.

Comment: i have added the modifier tab i hope it helps